# Поиск значений через таблицу отношений одним sql запросом

Tags: sql

Есть две таблицы с условными значениями.
1) В первой таблице указаны вперемешку три члена семьи: отец, мать, сын.
Таблица `Family` состоит из столбцов: Тип члена семьи (отец, мать или сын), Уникальный текстовый идентификатор, Имя члена семьи.
Например:

```
Type | Uid  | Name  
-------------------
Отец | xabc | Олег  
Отец | klae | Андрей  
 Сын | pord | Валерий  
Мать | rito | Елена  
 Сын | elkt | Иван  
Мать | lopr | Таня
```

2) Во второй таблице `Relation` указаны их отношения через `Uid`
Например:

```
Uid  | RelatedUid  
------------------
xabc | elkt  
xabc | rito  
pord | klae  
pord | lopr  
....
lopr | pord  
lopr | klae
```

Я хочу найти отцов и их сыновей, и у меня должна получится следующая таблица:

```
Отец | Сын  
----------------
Олег | Иван  
Андрей | Валерий
```

Можно ли это сделать одним sql запросом? И как это сделать?

Comment: а в чем сложность возникает? Вроде надо взять первую таблицу, приделать к ней таблицу связи, и еще раз приделать первую таблицу, где в перво случае выбирать отца, во втором сына. Из описания не ясно правда, кто кому отцом является а кто сыном из пары в отношении.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Как то так:

```
SELECT f.Name AS Отец, s.Name AS Сын FROM Relations AS r
INNER JOIN Persons AS f ON r.Uid = f.Uid
INNER JOIN Persons  AS s ON r.RelatedUid = s.Uid
WHERE f.Type = 'Отец' AND s.Type = 'Сын';
```

Или так

```
SELECT f.Name AS Отец, s.Name AS Сын FROM Relations AS r
INNER JOIN 
    (SELECT * FROM Persons WHERE Type = 'Отец' ) AS f ON r.Uid = f.Uid
INNER JOIN 
    (SELECT * FROM Persons WHERE Type = 'Сын') AS s ON r.RelatedUid = s.Uid;
```

В зависимости от структуры ваших данных, сервера и тд, может оказаться удобным тот или иной способ.

[ПРОВЕРКА](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/731d9e/3)

P.S. Надо так же заметить, что вы зря тип связи вносите в таблицу персон, логичней было бы внести её в таблицу связей.

Comment: Работает! На самом деле нет никаких "отцов" и "сыновей", есть более сложные сущности, которые наплодил не я. Я их упростил для понимания постановки задачи. Ваш код я переделал под себя. Спасибо.